# Get all class elements from html code as txt file using php

Tags: php, html, download, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get all span elements with class="msgsource" from my website's html code and then send it to the browser to download as a .txt file. this is what I have, but it download an empty text file

```
<?php
// parse div content
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
$code = $html->find('[@class="msgsource"]');
$content = $code->outertext;

// send content to browser
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . sizeof($content));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mylog.txt');
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: The @ shouldn't be there, you're mixing up your css and xpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the library that I am thinking check this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm, to find elements with specific class you change find param like this

```
$html->find('.msgsource');
```

You have there examples how to find all spans from the content too.

Comment: yes I'm using same library. I used    $html->find('.msgsource');    but it still downloads and empty file

Comment: You are recieving an empty log file because the domain example.com does not contain any span elements with the class="msgsource" which you are searching for, hence there is no html element that is found and hence the log is empty - check here : view-source:http://www.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// parse div content
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm');
$code = $html->find('span[class=comment]');
echo count($code);
echo $code[1];
?>
```

Use this format to find html elements :

```
 $code = $html->find('span[class=comment]');
```

The resultant will be stored in $code as an array and then access individual array elements (html element text contents) using their indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simple case that shows that it should work:

```
$str = <<<EOF
  <div class="msgsource">foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div class="msgsource">baz</div>
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);

$content = '';
foreach($html->find('.msgsource') as $code){
  $content .= $code->outertext . "\n";
}

echo $content;
```

From there, you can work backwards to try to figure out what's wrong in your case.